# Set element i,j in matrix to i^j in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I Need to specify a **n * m matrix with Elements of i^j in Matlab.**
I am totally new at this and Need some help.
Just found how to fill it with i * j Elements:

```
A= (1:n).'*(1:m).*ones(n,m);
```

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can exploit [singleton expansion](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/), using [`bsxfun`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
A = bsxfun(@power, (1:n).', (1:m));
```

In recent Matlab versions (R2016b onwards), thanks to implicit singleton expansion you can skip `bsxfun` and write directly

```
A = (1:n).'.^(1:m);
```

---

Or, for a more readable, beginner-friendly version, you can explicitly make two matrices of the same size with [`ndgrid`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html) and then apply `.^` ([element-wise power](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/power.html)):

```
[ii, jj] = ndgrid(1:n, 1:m);
A = ii.^jj;
```

---

Yet another approach is to replace power by repeated multiplication using [`cumprod`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumprod.html):

```
A = cumprod(repmat((1:n).', 1, m), 2);
```

Comment: Do you know how to implement this:  
**A_{i, j} = 1, If i = j+1 or i = j-1   (0, else)**

can I do this with `bsxfun(@eq `?

Comment: You can do it with `bsxfun(@minus, ...)`. I think what you want is `abs(bsxfun(@minus, (1:n).', (1:m)))==1`. Check also the `diag` function